# Z-Transform of $ x(n+2)u(n) $

Tags: discrete-signals, z-transform

I don't know where I went wrong, this might be a dumb question. I am solving for the z-transform of $$ y(n) = x(n+2)u(n) $$.
To solve, I used the z-transform equation,
$$ Y(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty y(n)z^{-n} $$
Now,
$$ Y(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x(n+2) u(n) z^{-n} $$
The unit step function changes the lower limit of the summation,
$$ Y(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x(n+2) z^{-n} $$
$$ Y(z) = x(2)z^{-0} + x(3)z^{-1} + x(4)z^{-2} + ... $$
$$ Y(z) = \sum_{n=2}^\infty x(n) z^{-n + 2} $$
$$ Y(z) = z^{2} \sum_{n=2}^\infty x(n) z^{-n} $$
$$ Y(z) = z^{2} \sum_{n=2}^\infty x(n) z^{-n} $$
Here, I returned it to having a 0 as lower limit,
$$ Y(z) = z^{2} (\sum_{n=0}^\infty x(n) z^{-n} - x(0) - x(1)z^{-1}) $$
This becomes my FINAL ANSWER,
$$ Y(z) = z^{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty x(n) z^{-n} - z^2 x(0) - zx(1) $$

However, the answer my professor gave is,
$$ Y(z) = z^{2} X(z) - z^2 x(0) - zx(1) $$

Where
$$ X(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x(n) z^{-n} $$
From what I know, it should be this way (mind the lower limits),
$$ X(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x(n) z^{-n}  $$
and the inverse z-Transform of $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty x(n) z^{-n} $ is $ x(n)u(n) $.
This would suggest that,
$$ X(z) \neq \sum_{n=0}^\infty x(n) z^{-n} $$

Comment: Your result is correct. I think your professor is talking about the unilateral Z-transform, or - equivalently - $x[n]$ is assumed to be causal, i.e., $x[n]=0$ for $n<0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@lukasdante, I believe Matt L. is correct. Your solution is equal to your professor's solution where $$ X(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x(n) z^{-n} $$ is the "one-sided z-transform" of a finite-duration time-domain signal sequence. A transform that is useful in practice. So I say to you: "Good Job."

The z-transform $$ Y(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty y(n)z^{-n} $$ applies to unreal infinite-duration time-domain sequences. I say "unreal" because in the physical world (the real world in which you live) there have never been, and can never be infinite-duration time-domain sequences. And, sadly, I believe all the region of conversion (ROC) theory about which the professors lecture has no practical meaning.

Comment: I don't see the two-sided $z$ transform used much, I think it's because of the whole ROC problem.  Usually if you're using a signal $x(n),\ n \in (-\infty, \infty)$ (which is a pretty good approximation for "starts before I care, ends after I care") you do your analysis using the Fourier transform, because then you don't have to worry about all that ROC stuff.